# Can't get html of a website, getting 302

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get contents of a Website with simple html DOM as follows:

```
<?php
 include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');

 $html =  file_get_html('http://www.opaltransfer.com/en');

 echo($html);      
?>
```

When i run this on my localhost everything works fine, However when i try to run it on a remote server i am getting

```
Found

The document has moved here.
```

Why? and what can i do to get it to work? Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your site redirected?

Comment: Vote for duplicate, because `simple_html_dom` internally uses `file_get_contents`. So this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6009316/697154) should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `/` at the end of the URL.

Comment: wow...... i'm speechless, thank you so much, i am a bit curious as to why does it not require the "/" on the localhost to work though? again thank you a lot, will accept the answer in 2 minutes

Comment: Different version of php? Recent versions follow redirects by default, not sure about older ones.