# PHP invalid connection Error (Curl / file_get_contents)

Tags: javascript, php, curl, file-get-contents

I try to take some information from a site lets call it x site (http://212.237.41.34/player.php?ch=b3)
When i try to connect that site from my pc it redirect me to http://www.cndhlsstream.pw/ site.

---

This is my problem; when i try to get content of x site with curl or file_get_contents it returns me only "invalid connection".

How can i solve this problem ?

I see on the bottom of x site there is a script

```
<script>
            if (top.location == self.location) {
                top.location = "http://www.cndhlsstream.pw/";
            }
 </script>
```

I think this make this error but i cannot make any solution.

---

I try this but it still return invalid connection

```
$context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'follow_location' => false
            )
        )
    );

    echo file_get_contents('http://212.237.41.34/player.php?ch=b3',false,$context);
```

Comment: Use [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) or `str_replace` to remove the script before rendering it. Since cURL and file_get_contents is not able to process the script elements.

Comment: Show your cURL script please.

Comment: function Baglan ($url) {

  $ch = curl_init ();
  curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
   CURLOPT_URL => $url,
   CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
     'Connection: keep-alive'
   ),
   CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'php/' . PHP_VERSION . ', libcurl/' . curl_version () ['version'],
   CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
   CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true 
  ) );
  echo $ch;
  $cikti = curl_exec ( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );
  
  return str_replace(array("\n","\t","\r"), null,$cikti);
 }

Answer (score 2):

by default, neither curl nor file_get_contents send an user-agent header, nor do they send `Connection: keep-alive`. this website of yours is weird, it requires an user agent, AND it requires the header `Connection: keep-alive`, else it will respond with "invalid connect", so send both those headers to avoid the error. here's an (working) example with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init ();
curl_setopt_array ( $ch, array (
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://212.237.41.34/player.php?ch=b3',
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array (
                'Connection: keep-alive'  // the server will just say "invalid connect" unless this header is sent, no idea why
        ),
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'php/' . PHP_VERSION . ', libcurl/' . curl_version () ['version'], // without a useragent, the server will also say "invalid connect"
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '', // <<the server supports gzip, this will make the transfer compressed, making it much faster
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true  // <<makes curl print lots of useful debugging info
) );
curl_exec ( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

also note that curl is faster than file_get_contents, primarily for 2 reasons, 1: curl stops reading on `content-length` bytes, file_get_contents ignore this header, and just keeps reading until the connection is closed, which can be much slower. 2: curl supports compressed transfers (gzip & deflate), which file_get_contents does not support, and html compresses very, very well (easily 3-5 times smaller than its uncompressed counterparts in some tests i ran way back), and curl_ code works regardless of php.ini options, whereas file_get_contents rely on the `allow_url_fopen` php.ini option being enabled.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome answer! It works but this time it redirect me to http://www.cndhlsstream.pw/ when curl_exec run, is there a way i stop it ?

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut Add `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true` to your `curl_setop_array` like so: `curl_set_opt_array($ch, array( ... CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,));` and then `curl_exec` will return the data instead of output it. You can then assign a variable to store the data `$output = curl_exec($ch);` See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut yeah that's a javascript redirect for some reason,. you can add CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, and strip out the redirect code like this ```$response = curl_exec ( $ch );
/* remove redirect */
$response = str_replace ( 'top.location = "http://www.cndhlsstream.pw/";', ';', $response );
echo $response;```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a user agent for the external web server to accept your request.

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'user_agent' => 'any'
    ]
]);

$output = file_get_contents('http://212.237.41.34/player.php?ch=b3', false, $context);
```

To prevent the redirect use `str_replace` to extract the command.

```
$output = str_replace('top.location = "http://www.cndhlsstream.pw/";', '', $output);
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: @AhmetKarabulut did you receive the same `invalid connection` error? As I only receive the error without the `'user_agent' => 'any'` flag being supplied.  It should be identical to the cURL answer, except you can also use the `str_replace` to remove the Javascript redirect in either answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'follow_location' => false   //dont not follow redirect 
        )
    )
);

$html = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);

var_dump($http_response_header);
```

refer : [How do I ignore a moved-header with file_get_contents in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009284/how-do-i-ignore-a-moved-header-with-file-get-contents-in-php)

Comment: I see that topic and try that but it still return invalid connection

Comment: did you try this one too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens

Comment: cURL and file_get_contents is not able to process `script` html elements. Processing occurs on the client side.

Comment: similar to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6902955/file-get-contents-script-works-with-some-websites-but-not-others