# How to find out the end url upon redirection

Tags: php, redirect, file-get-contents

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the real URL after file_get_contents if redirection happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens)

I'm using `file_get_contents('http://someurl.com/1893849')` to get contents of a url, but the url gets redirected. For example `/1893849` ends up at `/some-url-path`. Is there a way, in addition to getting the file contents, to also know the end path?

Comment: Possible repost of this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/4323985/971312

Comment: Not via `file_get_contents`. Look into using the `cURL` library and play around with `curl_setopt()` - `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use curl example :](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/curl-example.htm)

```
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
```

if you need know adres of redirec

```
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($init, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:') );
```

---

```
if ( strstr($content, 'Moved Temporarily') or  
strstr($content, 'Moved Permanently') or strstr($content, '302 Found')   ) :

if ( preg_match('@Location: (.*?)\n@', $content, $red) ) :

print_r($red);

endif;
```

Comment: It probably isn't a good idea to look for the English strings `Moved Temporarily` or `Moved Permanently` or `302 Found`. Checking the very first line of output for the status code (and only the status code) would be far more robust.