# Get Twitter profile picture actual link

Tags: php, twitter, file-get-contents

I'm trying to get the twitter profile picture actual link.
I know I can get the profile picture through the following link:

```
 $test = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/profile_image?screen_name=".$nickname."&size=original"
```

but when I want to get the file contents of this url, it doesn't work, cause above mentioned link is redirected to the actual link of the profile picture. So this doesn't work:

```
  file_get_contents($test);
```

How can I get the actual link of the profile picture and then with the size original?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the real URL after file_get_contents if redirection happens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens)

Comment: Not a duplicate, but this can be answered using information from that question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it might help you.

```
<?php
function getTwitterProfileImage($username) {
      $size = '_bigger';
      $api_call = 'http://twitter.com/users/show/'.$username.'.json';
      $results = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_call));
      return str_replace('_normal', $size, $results->profile_image_url);
}
$img =  getTwitterProfileImage('thetutlage');
echo '<img src="'.$img.'"/>';
 ?>
```

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but I can't get it to work. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: {"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}

Comment: @AmanVirk http://twitter.com/users/show/screen_name.json works no more. Any other workaround available?

Comment: For those who still search: As the right question :) - [How to get user image with Twitter API 1.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14836956/367456)

Answer (score 0):

Try this is up+direct,

```
<img class="img-rounded" src="<?php 
    $size = ''; 
    echo str_replace('_normal', $size,$tweet->user->profile_image_url)
?>" 
height="250px" width="400px" />
```