# How could I use PHP to get page by URL, which redirects to local path?

Tags: php, html, redirect, web

I'm trying to get page content by URL (e.g. '`http://example.com/page.html`') using PHP, but remote server redirects it to another page (e.g. '`http://example.com/another-page.html`') and when I try to execute code:

```
$p = file_get_contents('http://example.com/page.html');
echo $p;
```

browser returns 404 error:

```
The requested URL /another-page.html was not found on this server.
```

As I understand, instead of getting '`http://example.com/another-page.html`', PHP tries to return 'another-page.html' from my localhost and of course there is no such page. Seems like remote server redirects using local address ('`/another-page.html`' instead of '`http://example.com/another-page.html`') which is correct of course, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Could anybody advise me, how could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could use CURL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens some benefits: timeout-time and more information about redirect

Comment: I cannot reproduce, even with a technically invalid `Location:` header that uses relative paths. What's your PHP version?

Comment: @KevinvanHoorn - PHP stream wrappers support that stuff as well.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario - php 5.5.3+dfsg-1ubuntu2.1

Comment: ÁlvaroG.Vicario, KevinvanHoorn - thanks, I'll try both CURL and PHP stream wrappers.

Comment: Works fine for me on PHP/5.5.9 (Win). I've even tried with PHP/5.3.0. Are you 100% sure that such `/another-page.html` belongs to your local default site? Can you create the page manually and get redirected to it? (BTW, you are already using stream wrappers, that's why `file_get_contents` actually works even though there's no *file*.)