# How to get redirected page url using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am using **file_get_contents()** function to get a page source. When I am trying to get the source of http://example.com, which is internally redirected to http://example-new.com. Here I am getting the source of second URL. Is there any solutions to get **second URL** to identify to which URL it is redirected to.

Comment: i don't understand the question. some code will help too.

Comment: its 301 redirect http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens

Answer (score -1):

Just make request, wait for 200 and check url. I would recommend reading about curl.

Comment: That's not quite an answer.