# I can't get scraping from the usaspending.gov api to work

Tags: php, api, web-scraping

I'm getting errors while scraping data from usaspending.gov can I can't figure out why. I've checked that my php settings are all open and even setup a test scrape of another random site url.

I took another step to include options with the method and useragent.

I suspect it's timing out, but if that's not it, I'm not sure what else to try to get this to work. Every other url I try, I have no problem getting into. If anyone has any suggestions, I'd love to read them!!

Here's my sample code.

```
$opts = array(
      'http'=>array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'user_agent'=>"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8",
        'timeout'=>60
      )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $test = file_get_contents('http://www.usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?state=MI&detail=c&fiscal_year=2013',false,$context);
```

I'll also add, I've tried this with fopen, file_get_contents, and simplexml_load_file with no luck. I've tried it with the extended options on fopen and file_get_contents, no change. I'm sure I'm missing something small, just can't figure out what it is.

Edit: Here's the error message

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?state=MI&detail=c&fiscal_year=2013) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in...
```

Additionally, the link works I'm trying to open, if you copy/paste it into your browser, you should get the download.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: my bad, just added the error message up above

Comment: The error says "404 Not Found". That means that the URL is wrong or something is wrong on the remote server.

Comment: If you copy/paste the link into your browser, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After beating my head against this same wall for a while, I used a curl method ([How to get the real URL after file_get_contents if redirection happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens)) to find where the basic API URL was redirecting and that seems to be working now!

Instead of getting your same error message with:

```
file_get_contents(http://www.usaspending.gov/fpds/fpds.php?detail=c&fiscal_year=2013&state=AL&max_records=1000&records_from=0)
```

It is now working for me with:

```
file_get_contents(http://www.usaspending.gov/api/fpds_api_complete.php?fiscal_year=2013&vendor_state=AL&Contracts=c&sortby=OBLIGATED_AMOUNT%2Bdesc&records_from=0&max_records=20&sortby=OBLIGATED_AMOUNT+desc)
```

So pretty much using this as my base URL to access the API with more parameters added on (with the "Contracts" parameter replacing the original "detail" parameter):

http://www.usaspending.gov/api/fpds_api_complete.php?Contracts=c&sortby=OBLIGATED_AMOUNT%2Bdesc&sortby=OBLIGATED_AMOUNT+desc

I hope this helps, and works for you too!