# How to get final_url using the URL Fetch PHP API on Google App Engine?

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

Like the Python URL Fetch API, isn't there any way of getting the final_url in PHP on Google App Engine. Here's how its accessed in [Python](http://shell.appspot.com/):

```
>>> from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
>>> urlfetch.fetch('http://google.com/').final_url
'http://www.google.com/'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, other than disabling follow_location and parsing $http_response_header manually (See [How to get the real URL after file_get_contents if redirection happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens)) there's currently no way to get the final_url directly.

Comment: Yeah, am aware of that but that's not the most optimal approach (unlike the Python one). May be it would help to have a native PHP object mapped to urlfetch that exposes all that the API has to offer.

Comment: Feel free to add a feature request here: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language%3DPHP