# file_get_contents request to external site

Tags: php, json, apache, http, file-get-contents

I am trying to do a file_get_contents of this [Demo URL](http://spotifycharts.com/api/?type=regional&country=nl&recurrence=daily&date=latest&limit=200)
However the server has trouble with getting data from external sites. This is the error I get if I echo the file_get_contents:

> **Found The document has moved 
>   [here](http://spotifycharts.com/api/?type=regional&country=nl&recurrence=daily&date=latest&limit=200). Apache/2.4 Server at spotifycharts.com Port 80**

I have turned the `register_global` on in the **`php.ini file`**, but this doesn't help.

What would be the most logical thing to check to make sure my website is able to get data from external sites?

Comment: have u tried using curl?

Comment: No. Could you please explain what that is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the real URL after file\_get\_contents if redirection happens?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens)

Comment: You need to use cURL for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens

Comment: it seems here problem with 301 redirect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the https url instead of the http url:

https://spotifycharts.com/api/?type=regional&country=nl&recurrence=daily&date=latest&limit=200

Comment: Simplicity! It works. Have to wait to accept answer for 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

You may need to request with cURL, I don't think `file_get_contents()` can follow 302 redirects.

Something like this should work...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$a = curl_exec($ch);
if (preg_match('#Location: (.*)#', $a, $r))
  $l = trim($r[1]);
```

[How to get the real URL after file_get_contents if redirection happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4323985/462627)
[Source](http://zzz.rezo.net/HowTo-Expand-Short-URLs.html)