# Parsing JSON in PHP is not giving response

Tags: php, json, parsing

So I am trying to get some information from a JSON file. But for some reason there is no actual response with the information that I need.

This is the code im running.

```
$json_object = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$steamID.'/inventory/json/730/2');
$json_decoded = json_decode($json_object); 
echo $json_decoded->success;
```

I get the steamID from a cookie. But if you want to see how the JSON looks, then you can check out this link:
http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198031313244/inventory/json/730/2

Comment: What do you inside `$json_object` ?

Comment: May be its not utf8 ? What in $json_object ?

Comment: and what do u expect, its give me a long json response.. and getting `echo $json_decoded->success; is 1`

Comment: Are you sure `$json_object` is not empty? make sure that `file_get_contents()` is working as expected

Comment: I put in the steamcommunity.com/id/SANDISS/inventory/json/730/2 link and still got no response. Also if you look inside of the link at the very top, it should output "true"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the URL you are checking is redirected to another URL, `file_get_contents()` doesn't support following redirects AFAIK, so you should better use `cURL`

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4324018/5658508

Answer (score 0):

the problem is like the others tell you is in this  link http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198031313244/inventory/json/730/2

i just monitor the response, so when you visit the link you get a `302 Moved Temporarily` http response to the new link which is http://steamcommunity.com/id/SANDISS/inventory/json/730/2

you can try to get contents using file_get_contents if you have the link not just a steam id, or use `curl` library