# Why can I access a URL on with a browser but not with code?

Tags: php, python, json, url

I am trying to get a JSON object from a URL. I have tried using PHP (both `file_get_contents` and curl) and Python (both using `urllib2` and `requests`).
All error, but if I go to the URL with a browser it shows the JSON object. This is for my app on Apache2.

Here are the errors Im getting per command:

- file_get_contents --- failed to open stream
- cURL --- error 28: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
- Python request --

  ```
  File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
      response= requests.get(url, timeout=2)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
      return request('get', url, * *kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
      return session.request(method=method, url=url, *kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
      resp = self.send(prep, * *send_kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
      r = adapter.send(request, * *kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 387, in send
      raise Timeout(e)
  requests.exceptions.Timeout: (<urllib3.connectionpool.VerifiedHTTPSConnection instance at 0x7fbb3ec6d440>, 'Connection to **url** timed out. (connect timeout=2)')
  ```

I also tried running file_get_contents using a php online emulator just incase it was something with my server but I got this error

```
E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed -- at line 4
E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto -- at line 4
```

The curl code is:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ( $result==false ) {
  echo curl_errno($ch).' '.curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What does your curl command look like exactly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more

Comment: is the URL you are trying to reach an HTTPS address (as your results with the online emulator seem to suggest)?  if so, what are you doing to pass the required credentials?

Comment: Possibly link to redirection. YOu can find answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens)

Comment: yeah its an http address which requires a username and apikey, but thats included in the address

Comment: Also, I don't believe its redirected cause the url in the browser once the page is loaded is the same as what the code has... unless you can redirect without it showing in the address bar, which sounds hella sketch

Comment: Would be nice to see your actual Python code