# Downloading .xlsx file from URL using PHP

Tags: php, excel, sharepoint, xlsx

I'm having issues downloading an excel file onto my web server from a URL using PHP. The file is publicly accessible on a Microsoft Sharepoint server and downloads automatically when accessed directly via the link. Here is my code:

```
$url = 'https://example.sharepoint.com/somefile.xlsx?download=1';
$file = file_put_contents('template.xlsx', file_get_contents($url));
```

The script successfully creates the template.xlsx file on the server, however the file itself is 0 bytes and when I try to open it I get an error along the lines of "Excel cannot open the file because the file format or file extension is invalid". What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing the link redirects or points to a page that requires JS? What headers do you get with `curl -D - <that url>`?

Comment: I recommend use cURL to download file instead. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409462/downloading-a-large-file-using-curl

Comment: @AlexHowansky With some info redacted...

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 517
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://sharepoint.com/somefile.xlsx
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
Set-Cookie: FedAuth=77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz48U1ATwvU1A+; path=/; SameSite=None; secure; HttpOnly
X-SharePointHealthScore: 1
X-MS-SPO-CookieValidator: sQ7YhnGeis9fooVHWZdO8h/x8DvNqgc6xlu+gISDPMUqcoghMO0mHlIx0mdU5L3BkP
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319

Comment: @AlexHowansky
X-DataBoundary: None
X-1DSCollectorUrl: https://mobile.events.data.microsoft.com/OneCollector/1.0/
X-AriaCollectorURL: https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/
SPRequestGuid: 3f9940a0-4045-d000-0d64-e62c63cd9263
request-id: 3f9940a0-4045-d000-0d64-e62c63cd9263
MS-CV: oECZP0VAANANZOYsY82SYw.0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' teams.microsoft.com *.teams.microsoft.com *.skype.com *

Comment: @AlexHowansky
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.22504
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
X-Cache: CONFIG_NOCACHE
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: A0C7A23C205E468EBA2A53226CB3FFAF Ref B: DEN301000102047 Ref C: 2022-05-24T18:49:31Z

Comment: @vee Initiating the download via cURL doesn't change the outcome. I still get an unreadable file.

Comment: `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` That's a redirect. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4323985/how-to-get-the-real-url-after-file-get-contents-if-redirection-happens) to follow redirects.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I think we're getting closer.. it's now downloading a file, but the contents are HTML saying the file has moved to another location (yet the browser still initiates a download during a normal copy/paste):

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/sites/example/Shared%20Documents/General/Clients/Client/Templates/file.xlsx?ga=1">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>