# If the last character is a "/", remove it

Tags: php, url, dom, substr

I am making a search engine from scratch (lol), and I am stick with this problem:

When a user submits a URL, my "spider" "crawls" it for other links.
Some people of course use `<a href="/page">` instead of `<a href="http://long-domain.com/page">`, so I detect that with 
`if(substr($link->getAttribute('href'), 0, 1) == '/')`

And add a domain in front of it. BUT, whenever I do add a domain, some links become `http://php.net//abcd`. As you can see its `//`.

Now, my idea was to make my script edit the submitted URL so if it has a slash at the end, it'll be removed, but I have no idea how to remove it.

Comment: Relative URLs are _a lot_ more complicated than just starting with a slash. In fact, **many** relative URLs do not begin with a slash at all - and still don't include a domain name.

Comment: ... and then you might have domain names in valid relative URLs (`/www.domain.com/pages`); and protocol-relative URLs `//domain.com/page`

Comment: I haven't experienced those problems before, I'll do a small detection. Thanks.

Comment: @user2153768 A link on `http://google.com/directory` may appear just as `index.html`, which means the result should be: `http://google.com/directory/index.html`. It may be `/index.html`, meaning it should be: `http://google.com/index.html`, or it could be `./index.html` or `../index.html` or any number of other combinations. This approach isn't likely to work well at all.

Comment: That could be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444475/transfrom-relative-path-into-absolute-url-using-php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [rtrim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php)

```
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
```

It will remove all `/` at the end of a string, or leave it unchanged if there are none

Comment: Except now this creates an additional problem with relative URLs that don't begin with a leading slash. You end up with `http://domain.comdirectory/file`

Comment: That was the answer to the question of how to remove the last `/`. About relative urls, he should just check if url is starting with `http`, and if it is, then it's absolute url

Comment: @MarkoD Checking if a URL has a scheme simply tells you if it's relative or absolute. It doesn't tell you how to resolve it at all. Also, yes - you did answer the question. But in doing so you created the exact _opposite_ problem (now, instead of double slashes on URLs he will end up with _no_ slashes on many URLs)

Comment: @ColinMorelli Nabab gave him a good link how to solve that problem, I just answered his initial question, though I understand your point :-)

Comment: @MarkoD I know - and I didn't downvote you. Just explaining why I commented in the first place.

Comment: @ColinMorelli Thanks, we have an understanding :)

Comment: I just reproduced the problem with this HTMLBIN - http://html-bin.appspot.com/aghodG1sLWJpbnIMCxIEUGFnZRiJ-GIM

Comment: can you explain in more details?

Comment: Like others said I solved the problem with `<a href="/page">` but created a new one with `<a href="page">`.

Comment: have a look at the link Nabab left you in a comment

Answer (score 1):

just do a string replace on the final url

```
<?php $final_url=str_replace("//","/",$your_link_to_be_crawled); ?>
```

that is simple enough.

to put the  // back after it affected the http://,

lets do `preg_replace`

```
<?php
$your_url_to_crawl;
$patterns = array(); $patterns[0] = '/http:/';$patterns[1] = '/https:/'; $patterns[2] = '/any_other_protocol/';
$replacements = array(); $replacements[2] = 'http://'; $replacements[1] = 'https://';$replacements[0] = 'any_other_protocol';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $your_url_to_crawl);
```

?>

Comment: OMG..dnt think abt that...hmmmmmmm

Comment: how about you remove the slashes the first time, of course the http:// will be affected then you put it back..look at my new answer

Comment: I thought about it, but I'll try something more efficient.

Comment: I did a little editing to my code just now and was able to somehow fix it.

Comment: post your answer please as this could help someone else

Comment: I used `ltrim();`. I really don't know how I did it but I used that function and I used `str_replace();`.

Comment: alright then...when ur done with the search engine be sure to let me know...lets take it for a test run...lol..

Comment: lol ok I'll post a comment on here. It's not done yet at all, I am just making an admin center where you add URLs, but I think it looks nice so far. Thanks for the help guys. I added a valid URL detection, so if a URL is invalid (eg "index.php" without a URL), it won't be added.