# Change the url of the ajax call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

i am using the curl to fetch the data  from the url link and is working fine but the issue is that the response data uses the ajax call but all these ajax call are using my server domain but i need them to use the original path of the ajax call, where the files are located. E.g

`/ajax/fetch.php` changes to `http://original-domain.com/ajax/fetch.php`

please tell me the appropriate solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You want to do something with curl but what? Can you show the code you already have?

Comment: You may be looking for a headless browser like phantomjs instead of curl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert a relative URL to an absolute one, take a look at this: [Transfrom relative path into absolute URL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444475/transfrom-relative-path-into-absolute-url-using-php)

Something like `rel2abs('/ajax/fetch.php', 'http://original-domain.com/ajax');`

Comment: I think his problem is not relative vs absolute url but same-origin policy. Absolute url is useless in ajax since you can only connect to your own server anyway. Unless of course you want to use CORS.

Comment: same origin is irrelevant, the calls are being made with curl, not the web browser.

Comment: If it's using curl then it's not ajax. It's only ajax when it's done in the web browser. I think we're not getting the full picture of what he's trying to do.