# Comparing two URLs from the browsers perspective

Tags: php, shell, url

If I have two URLs in PHP (e.g. `/r/jquery.js` and `http://domain.tld/r/jquery.js`), is there a clean way to compare those two, interpreted in a way the browser would interpret them when visiting a specified URL?

So for this comparison, three URLs are given:

- `$url_a` - the URL to compare with `$url_b`
- `$url_b` - the URL to compare with `$url_a`
- `$url_c` - the base for relative URLs

For example:
If `$url_a = '/r/jquery.js'` and `$url_b = 'http://domain.tld/r/jquery.js'`, the comparison

- should give `true` if `$url_c = 'http://domain.tld/s/index.php'`
- should give `false` if `$url_c = 'https://domain.tld/s/index.php'`
- should give `false` if `$url_c = 'http://subdomain.domain.tld/s/index.php'`

I am searching for a **full solution** including facets like `/r///../r/jquery.js` *can* equal `http://domain.tld/r/jquery.js` (depending on `$url_c`) and much more.

Since there are probably more facets than a layman (as me) knows, I think a **library or built-in PHP-feature** would be required. While I would also be interested in Linux command line tools, that would not be the *best* bet, because my testing environment is windows, although I deploy to Linux.

Off-Topic / Background information:

> I am currently implementing a system into my website that manages JavaScript, CSS and other dependencies. For this sake I need to compare, whether a JavaScript file is already implemented/a dependency or not. But at that point I have only URLs to those files (Which is perfectly fine! I will not change that!).

Comment: I'd convert all URL'S to full paths and *then* compare them.

Comment: [Check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444475/transfrom-relative-path-into-absolute-url-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go is (as suggested by @scunliffe and @James):

Convert both to absolute URLs and then compare the strings equality.

https://github.com/monkeysuffrage/phpuri

EDIT:

Yet untested:

```php
require_once 'phpuri.php';
function urlsEqual($urlA, $urlB, $base) {
    $oBase = phpUri::parse($base);
    $oUrlA = $oBase->join($urlA);
    $oUrlB = $oBase->join($urlB);
    return $oUrlA == $oUrlB;
}

$url_a = '/r/jquery.js';
$url_b = 'http://domain.tld/r/jquery.js';
$url_c = 'http://domain.tld/s/index.php';
if(urlsEqual($url_a, $url_b, $url_c))
    echo $url_a.' == '.$url_b;
else
    echo $url_a.' != '.$url_b;
```