# file upload - selenium - Path not absolute

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I have written some phpunit selenium code to upload a file. I find it working perfectly fine in my local and the i have given the path of the file as

```
  $filePath = getcwd(). "/Images/test_Image1.png"
```

When I run the same piece of code in jenkins (running on saucelabs), the test fails saying the path is not absolute

```
 unknown error: path is not absolute: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/UploadProject/test_Image1.png (Session info: chrome=47.0.2526.73) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

but I can see that the image file exists on that path. So how should i give the absolute path here

Answer (score -1):

> So how should i give the absolute path here

See: [Transfrom relative path into absolute URL using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444475/transfrom-relative-path-into-absolute-url-using-php)

If you use not PHP, you can use sample from link like code example and create your function.

Comment: I am running the code on jenkins server and chrome driver expects a root directory like (C://) to check for absolute path. But since this is on jenkins, I do not know how to give the absolute path

Comment: For a start, print full error stack trace here, please. Nowbody knowns what you get and see.

Comment: If your really problem is relative path, I already answered how you can resolve it.

Comment: This is to transform relative path as a URL and not as a local file.