# Why Php Fails To Extract Titles Sometimes From Title Tags?

Tags: php, curl, web-crawler

The following code manages to extract title from title tags of some pages while fails to extract the title from other pages that do have their titles intact. I can't figureout why it misfires. I ran it on localhost.
This snippet should have worked:

```
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $doc->loadHTML( $contents['body'] );
    //Get title
    $title = '';
    $titleTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    if( count( $titleTags ) > 0 ) {
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $titleTags[0]->nodeValue );
    }
```

What is wrong with the above snippet ? It should've extracted the title from all pages that do have their titles intact.

```
$mysql_username = 'root';
$mysql_password = '';
$mysql_database = 'powerpage';
$mysql_conn = mysqli_connect( $mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database );
if ( !$mysql_conn ) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
/**
 * Download a Webpage via the HTTP GET Protocol using libcurl
 * Developed By: Potent Pages, LLC (https://potentpages.com/)
 */
function _http ( $target, $referer ) {
    //Initialize Handle
    $handle = curl_init();
    //Define Settings
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie_jar.txt" );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt" );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "web-crawler-tutorial-test" );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $target );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4 );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    //Execute Request
    $output = curl_exec ( $handle );
    //Close cURL handle
    curl_close ( $handle );
    //Separate Header and Body
    $separator = "\r\n\r\n";
    $header = substr( $output, 0, strpos( $output, $separator ) );
    $body_start = strlen( $header ) + strlen( $separator );
    $body = substr( $output, $body_start, strlen( $output ) - $body_start );
    //Parse Headers
    $header_array = Array();
    foreach ( explode ( "\r\n", $header ) as $i => $line ) {
        if($i === 0) {
            $header_array['http_code'] = $line;
            $status_info = explode( " ", $line );
            $header_array['status_info'] = $status_info;
        } else {
            list ( $key, $value ) = explode ( ': ', $line );
            $header_array[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    //Form Return Structure
    $ret = Array("headers" => $header_array, "body" => $body );
    return $ret;
}
/**
 * Convert Relative to Absolute URL
 * Developed By: Potent Pages, LLC (https://potentpages.com/)
 * From: https://potentpages.com/web-crawler-development/tutorials/php/simple-php-web-spider
 * Based On: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444475/transfrom-relative-path-into-absolute-url-using-php
 */
function relativeToAbsolute( $relative, $base )
{
    if($relative == "" || $base == "") return "";
    //Check Base
    $base_parsed = parse_url($base);
    if( !array_key_exists( 'scheme', $base_parsed ) || !array_key_exists( 'host', $base_parsed ) || !array_key_exists( 'path', $base_parsed ) ) {
        echo "Base Path \"$base\" Not Absolute Link\n";
        return "";
    }
    //Parse Relative
    $relative_parsed = parse_url($relative);
    //If relative URL already has a scheme, it's already absolute
    if( array_key_exists( 'scheme', $relative_parsed ) && $relative_parsed['scheme'] != '' ) {
        return $relative;
    }
    //If only a query or a fragment, return base (without any fragment or query) + relative
    if( !array_key_exists( 'scheme', $relative_parsed ) && !array_key_exists( 'host', $relative_parsed ) && !array_key_exists( 'path', $relative_parsed ) ) {
        return $base_parsed['scheme']. '://'. $base_parsed['host']. $base_parsed['path']. $relative;
    }
    //Remove non-directory portion from path
    $path = preg_replace( '#/[^/]*$#', '', $base_parsed['path'] );
    //If relative path already points to root, remove base return absolute path
    if( $relative[0] == '/' ) {
        $path = '';
    }
    //Working Absolute URL
    $abs = '';
    //If user in URL
    if( array_key_exists( 'user', $base_parsed ) ) {
        $abs .= $base_parsed['user'];
        //If password in URL as well
        if( array_key_exists( 'pass', $base_parsed ) ) {
            $abs .= ':'. $base_parsed['pass'];
        }
        //Append location prefix
        $abs .= '@';
    }
    //Append Host
    $abs .= $base_parsed['host'];
    //If port in URL
    if( array_key_exists( 'port', $base_parsed ) ) {
        $abs .= ':'. $base_parsed['port'];
    }
    //Append New Relative Path
    $abs .= $path. '/'. $relative;
    //Replace any '//' or '/./' or '/foo/../' with '/'
    $regex = array('#(/\.?/)#', '#/(?!\.\.)[^/]+/\.\./#');
    for( $n=1; $n>0; $abs = preg_replace( $regex, '/', $abs, -1, $n ) ) {}
    //Return Absolute URL
    return $base_parsed['scheme']. '://'. $abs;
}
function parsePage( $target, $referer ) {
    global $mysql_conn;
    //Parse URL and get Components
    $url_components = parse_url( $target );
    if($url_components === false) {
        die( 'Unable to Parse URL' );
    }
    $url_host = $url_components['host'];
    $url_path = '';
    if(array_key_exists( 'path', $url_components ) == false) {
        //If not a valid path, mark as done
        $query = "INSERT INTO pages (path, download_time) VALUES (\"". mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $target ). "\", NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE download_time=NOW()";
        if( !mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $query) ) {
            echo "Line 128";//MY OWN ADDED LINE
            die( "Error: Unable to perform Download Time Update Query (path)\n" );
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        $url_path = $url_components['path'];
    }
    //Download Page
    echo "Downloading: $target\n";
    $contents = _http ( $target, $referer );
    echo "Done\n";
    //Check Status
    if( $contents['headers']['status_info'][1] != 200 ) {
        //If not ok, mark as downloaded but skip
        $query = "INSERT INTO pages (path, download_time) VALUES (\"". mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $url_path ). "\", NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE download_time=NOW()";
        if( !mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $query) ) {
            echo "Line 144";//MY OWN ADDED LINE
            die( "Error: Unable to perform Download Time Update Query (http status)\n" );
        }
        return false;
    }
    //Parse Contents
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
    $doc->loadHTML( $contents['body'] );
    //Get title
    $title = '';
    $titleTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title');
    if( count( $titleTags ) > 0 ) {
        $title = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $titleTags[0]->nodeValue );
    }
    //Get Description
    $description = '';
    $metaTags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
    foreach( $metaTags as $tag ) {
        if( $tag->getAttribute('name') == 'description' ) {
            $description = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $tag->getAttribute( 'content' ) );
        }
    }
    //Get first h1
    $h1 = '';
    $h1Tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('h1');
    if( count( $h1Tags ) > 0 ) {
        $h1 = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $h1Tags[0]->nodeValue );
    }
    //Insert/Update Page Data
    $query = "INSERT INTO pages (path, title, description, h1, download_time) VALUES (\"". mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $url_path ). "\", \"$title\", \"$description\", \"$h1\", NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title=\"$title\", description=\"$description\", h1=\"$h1\", download_time=NOW()";
    if( !mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $query) ) {
        echo "Line 176";//MY OWN ADDED LINE
        die( "Error: Unable to perform Insert Query\n" );
    }
    //Get Links
    $links = Array();
    $link_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
    foreach( $link_tags as $tag ) {
        if( ($href_value = $tag->getAttribute( 'href' ))) {
            $link_absolute = relativeToAbsolute( $href_value, $target );
            $link_parsed = parse_url( $link_absolute );
            if($link_parsed === null || $link_parsed === false) {
                die( 'Unable to Parse Link URL' );
            }
            if(( !array_key_exists( 'host', $link_parsed ) || $link_parsed['host'] == "" || $link_parsed['host'] == $url_host ) && array_key_exists( 'path', $link_parsed ) && $link_parsed['path'] != "" && array_search( $link_parsed['path'], $links ) === false) {
                $links[] = $link_parsed['path'];
            }
        }
    }
    //Insert Links
    foreach($links as $link) {
        $link_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $link );
        $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO pages (path, referer, download_time) VALUES (\"$link_escaped\", \"". mysqli_real_escape_string( $mysql_conn, $target ). "\", NULL)";
        if( !mysqli_query($mysql_conn, $query) ) {
            echo "Line 199";//MY OWN ADDED LINE
            die( "Error: Unable to perform Insert Link Value Query\n" );
        }
    }
    return true;
}
//Define Seed Settings
$seed_url = "http://localhost/ebrute.com/crawler/5/1.php";
$seed_components = parse_url( $seed_url );
if($seed_components === false) {
    die( 'Unable to Seed Parse URL' );
}
$seed_scheme = $seed_components['scheme'];
$seed_host = $seed_components['host'];
$url_start = $seed_scheme. '://'. $seed_host;
//Download Seed URL
parsePage( $seed_url, "" );
//Loop through all pages on site.
while(1) {
    $counter = 0;
    $select_query = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE download_time IS NULL";
    if(($select_result = mysqli_query( $mysql_conn, $select_query )) !== false) {
        if( ($rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($select_result)) > 0 ) {
            for( $i = 0; $i < $rowCount; $i++ ) {
                if( ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_result) ) !== false ) {
                    $path = $row['path'];
                    $referer = $row['referer'];
                    //Check if first character isn't a '/'
                    if( $path[0] != '/' ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $path = $row['path'];
                    $referer = $row['referer'];
                    if( parsePage( $url_start. $path, $referer ) ) {
                        $counter++;
                    }
                    sleep(1);
                }
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } else {
        die( "Unable to select un-downloaded pages\n" );
    }
    if($counter == 0) {
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

Manages to extract from titles from 1.php which looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
1st Page Title
</title>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Page 1 description is this">
  <meta name="keywords" content="page, 1, one">
  <meta name="author" content="Mr 1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head> 
<body>
This is page <a href="2.php"> 2</a> or <a href="2.php">two</a>.
This is page <a href="10.php"> 10</a> or <a href="10.php">ten</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

Fails to extract from 2.php & 10.php.

2.php looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
2nd Page Title
</title>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Page 2 description is this">
  <meta name="keywords" content="page, 2, two">
  <meta name="author" content="Mr 2">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head> 
<body>
This is page <a href="3.php"> 3</a> or <a href="3.php">three</a>.
This is page <a href="20.php"> 20</a> or <a href="20.php">twenty</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

10.php looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
10th Page Title
</title>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Page 10 description is this">
  <meta name="keywords" content="page, 10, ten">
  <meta name="author" content="Mr 10">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head> 
<body>
This is page <a href="20.php"> 20</a> or <a href="20.php">twenty</a>.
This is page <a href="2.php"> 2</a> or <a href="2.php">two</a>.
</body>
</html>
```

These are my files on localhost (Xampp) for testing purpose.

Comment: Can you also include an HTML file for which it can't extract the title?

Comment: @rid12,

I added the html of the 2 files on my original post after editing it. - Thanks!

Comment: That's gobbledygook HTML, with nested `<head>` tags…

Comment: you're wrong, DOMDocument manage to extract the title from all of the above: https://3v4l.org/LrjBB

Comment: @deceze right you are, but it doesn't matter, DOMDocument is still able to extract the title tags, see my link above

Comment: @hanshenrik,I a beginner at php or programming and so excuse me if this sounds daft: "Care to tell me how you generated that above link ?".
And, what do you think the problem is ? Why the code failing to extract the titles from the title tag from time to time ?

Comment: @deceze,The code manages to grab the gobbledygook title from the gobbledecook page 1.php but not from 2.php & 3.php.Like I say, all 3 pages' html are similar. I built the pages just for web crawler testing purpose. I can't see why the code manages to extract the title from 1.php (another gobbledygook HTML) if the code was buggy. Scratching my head!

Comment: Have you verified that `$contents['body']` actually contains what you think it should? Just because the _files_ you have shown us might contain what you want, does not necessarily mean that is still the case for `$contents['body']`, if your `_http` function might have messed up parsing the HTTP response …

Comment: @Ali find the exact content of `$contents['body']` when you can't extract the title, because it's not any of the examples you've posted here =/ and if i'm wrong, then post a sample containing ONLY a $html variable with the html, and the title extraction code, nothing else. for example: https://3v4l.org/WDMiG

and how did i make that url? you can make one yourself by going to https://3v4l.org/ , write your code, and press "Eval"

Comment: I did echo the $contents['body'] and the page contents did get echoed. Originally, I said that, I set the crawler at 1.php and it successfully extracted it's title but not the title of the links it followed (2.php and 10.php). Now, I set the crawler to 2.php (failed page) and this time it successfully extracted it's title but it failed to extract the titles of the links it found on 2.php which it followed. It seems the crawler only manages to extract the title from the seed url ($seed_url) but fail to extract from any of the  links it follows. Have to figure-out the cause.