# preg_replace() relative paths to absolute path. (Masking?)

Tags: php, regex, filesystems, preg-replace, minify

I am in the process of trying to figure out how to mask a path over relative paths. This is a custom minifier script I'm implementing for CSS files, and need to absolute the relative paths.

So say I have the following in a CSS file `url('../images/file.jpg')` This file is sitting in the directory `/application/module/assets/css/theme.css`, this would mean the new path in the CSS file would need to be `/application/module/assets/images/file.jpg`.

Now say there is a CSS file in `/application/plugins/pluginName/assets/css/plugin.css` and links to `../../../../module/assets/images/image.jpg`, the replaced path would need to be `/application/module/assets/images/file.jpg`

So I'm asking, is there a nice preg_replace setup I can use to do this:

```
str_replace('../', '/path/to/file/', $file);
str_replace('../../', '/path/to/', $file);
str_replace('../../../', '/path/', $file);
```

Hopefully this makes sense...

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: Two thoughts: The "minified" version is not really any shorter, and this is more of a compiler than a minifier, since it changes what the CSS actually does. This just seems more trouble than it's worth to me. (What *is* it worth?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this from another question ([PHP: How to resolve a relative url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243418/php-how-to-resolve-a-relative-url)): [**PHP tip: How to convert a relative URL to an absolute URL**](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/79)

I think that the function you want is the `url_remove_dot_segments` function which takes a concatenated path (e.g. `$base . '/' . $path`) and returns a version with `//`, `/./` and `/../` removed.

Answer (score 1):

I also can't se much sense in your doing, but maybe the PHP function "realpath" is your friend.

Comment: Also, if you need the directory in which the file is : `dirname(realpath('./filename.php'))`