# In Java, convert a filepath to canonical form?

Tags: java, file, filepath, canonical-link

I want to write an algorithm to convert an arbitrary filepath to canonical form (i.e. remove any "." and ".." where "." means "current directory", and ".." means "up one level"). I've removed the "." correctly, that part's easy.

For example:

```
/web/foo/bar/../baz/../../blat/./../foobie/bletch.html
```

should become

```
/web/foobie/bletch.html
```

and

```
www/someDir/./index.html
```

should become

```
www/someDir/index.html
```

and

```
www/someDir/./index.html
```

should become

```
www/index.html
```

This is my code so far:

```
public static String makeCanonical(String uri) {
    String canonical="";
    System.out.println("+" + uri); //for testing, doesn't need to print
    ArrayList<String> parts=new ArrayList<String>();
    int currentIndex=0;

    //split string at every '/' into an ArrayList substring
    for(int i=0; i<uri.length(); i++){
        if(uri.charAt(i)=='/'){
            parts.add(uri.substring(currentIndex, i+1));
            currentIndex=i+1;

        }
    }
    //trying to go up one level at every '..'  ;  not working correctly
    for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){
        if(parts.get(i).contains("..")){
            parts.remove(i);
            parts.remove(i-1);
        }
    }
    //compile all parts into single string
    for(int i=0; i<parts.size(); i++){
        canonical=canonical+parts.get(i);
    }
    //discard and '.' (single dot) characters
    canonical=canonical.replaceAll("/./", "/");
    if(canonical.contains(".")){

    }
    System.out.print("-" + canonical); //printing for testing
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();
    return canonical;
}
```

This is my output in the form

```
+(original)
-(output)
```

-

```
+www/index.html
-www/

+/web/foo/bar/../baz/../../blat/./../foobie/bletch.html
-/web/foo/baz/blat/foobie/

+www/someDir/
-www/someDir/

+www/someDir/anotherDir/../../index.html
-www/someDir/../
```

Comment: This is an exercise? Why aren't you using `java.nio.file.Path`? Or looking at some of its built-in implementations?

Comment: That's a start. Now, what's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: this is homework?  you can't use any builtin functionality?

Comment: Another bug you've not discovered as far as I can see: `replaceAll("/./", ...` applied to `/x/` would result in `/` because that method assumes you're providing a regular expression and `.`  means "any character" not the literal `.`.

Comment: No, we can't use a built-in functionality. It's part of a larger assignment, we have to write this method.

Comment: @zapl how do I denote the literal `.`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674930/java-regex-meta-character-and-ordinary-dot e.g. `replaceAll("/\\./"` or use `.replace("/./", "/")` which also replaces all but does not assume regex syntax and is a wonderful example of inconstistent naming.

Comment: Okay. any idea how to fix the other issue?

Comment: How does `www/someDir/./index.html` become `www/index.html`?

Comment: Which version of Java is that by the way? If this is Java 8 you can use a `Collector` to great effect here

Comment: I outlined the basic algorithm for doing this in an [answer to a PHP question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14883803/862594)