# Convert relative URL to absolute URL

Tags: regex, bash, url

Input:

- Base URL: `www.example.com/1/2/index.php`
- Relative URL: `../../index.php`

Output:

- Absolute URL: `www.example.com/index.php`

It would be perfect, of it would be done using **sed**.

As I understand, this regex should delete one `somefolder/` in for every `../` in the URL.

Comment: this is almost dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444475/transfrom-relative-path-into-absolute-url-using-php

Answer (score 1):

If your only requirement is to turn `..` into "up one level" then this is a possible solution. It doesn't use regular expressions or sed, or a JVM for that matter ;)

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                

domain="www.example.com"
origin="1/2/3/4/index.php"
rel="../../index.php"

awk -v rel="$rel" -v origin="$origin" -v file="$(basename "$rel")" -v dom="$domain" '                                                                
BEGIN {                                                                                                                                    
    n = split(rel, a, "/")                                                                                                                 
    for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {                                                                                                              
        if(a[i] == "..") ++c                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                      
    abs = dom                                                                                                                              
    m=split(origin, b, "/")                                                                                                                
    for(i = 1; i < m - c; ++i) {                                                                                                           
        abs=abs"/"b[i]                                                                                                                     
    }                                                                                                                                      
    print abs"/"file                                                                                                                       
}'
```

An alternative approach to using `awk`, credit to Edward for mentioning `realpath -m`:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                

rel="../../index.php"
origin="www.example.com/1/2/index.php"

directory=$(dirname "$origin")
fullpath=$(realpath -m "$directory/$rel")
echo "${fullpath#$(pwd)/}"
```

Answer (score 1):

`realpath` is a quick but slightly hacky way to do what you want.
(Actually, I'm surprised that it doesn't deal properly with URLs; it treats them as plain old filesystem paths.)
`~$ realpath -m http://www.example.com/1/2/../../index.php` =>
`~$ /home/username/http:/www.example.com/index.php`
The `-m` (for "missing") says to resolve the path even if components of it don't actually exist on the filesystem.
So you'll still have to strip off the actual filesystem part of that (which will just be `$(pwd)`. And note that the slash-slash for the protocol was also canonicalized to a single slash. So you might be better off to leave the "http://" off of your input and just prepend it to your output instead.
See `man 1 realpath` for the full story.  Or `info coreutils 'realpath invocation'` for a more verbose full story, if you have the info system installed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` inside `bash`

```
#!/bin/bash

base_url='www.example.com/1/2/index.php'
rel_url='../../index.php'

str="${base_url};${rel_url}"
str=$(echo $str | sed -r 's#/[^/]*;#/#')
while [ ! -z $(echo $str | grep '\.\.') ]
do
  str=$(echo $str | sed -r 's#\w+/\.\./##')
done
abs_url=$str

echo $abs_url
```

Output:

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

Answer (score -3):

You can't use a single regular expression for this, because regular expressions can't count.

You should use a real programming language instead. Even Java can do this easily.