# How to extract image from website with simple-html-dom?

Tags: php, image, parsing, html-parsing, simple-html-dom

How to extract images from website and download them in a local file with **simple-html-dom** to load them from file **to avoid loading images each time** from their original web site.

```
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://www.caradisiac.com/');
    foreach( $html->find('.featured img') as $image ){
        echo $image->src;
        echo "<br>";
    }
```

Help me please!!

Comment: Please post the code that you have put together so far -- Stack Overflow is for solving specific programming problems; it is not a coding service. Have you searched for similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 - Be sure you've read [*PHP manual*](http://en.php.net) to see all the amazing built-in functions PHP has.

1 - Build a local path for the image, you may use [`preg_replace`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to sanitize the URL

2 - Check the image hasn't already been downloaded using [`file_exists`](http://www.php.net/file_exists), if so, load it; else download it

3 - Use [`file_get_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to retrieve the image ([`cURL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) would be uselessly heavier)

4 - Save it to a local file using [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php)

```
foreach( $html->find('.featured img') as $image )
{
    $imageSrc = $image->src;
    $imageUri = $this->rel2abs($imageSrc, $sourceURI);
    $imageLocalPath = 'getImages/'.preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-.]/i', '-', $imageUri);

    if (!file_exists($imageLocalPath))
    {
        $imageData = file_get_contents($imageUri, false, $streamContext);
        file_put_contents($imageLocalPath, $imageData);
    }
    else
        $imageData = file_get_contents($imageLocalPath);
}
```

---

**Notes:**

- You need [`rel2abs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1243431/2342518) to resolve relative URIs, or any appropriate pecl extension.
- *getImages/* will put all images in a subfolder: you need to manually create that subfolder, or check its existence in the PHP code and create it if needed
- $imageData contains the raw data of the image, you may which to use [`imagecreatefromstring`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) to load the corresponding Gd image.
- Take care: you're downloading stuff from a distant webpage, so you must trust it well. One could add a tag like `<div class="featured"><img src="http://evil.com/your-heart-will-bleed.php"/></div>` in the html page, and the evil php file will be downloaded. Worst, it may be executed by visiting your website `http://mywebsite.com/getImages/your-heart-will-bleed.php`.

Comment: Where do you get $sourceURI from?

Comment: `$sourceURI` is the web page URI you are calling (here, `http://www.caradisiac.com/`). It is required because `$image->src` can be relative (while here, you need an absolute URI for calling `file_get_contents`).